# The implication: $x+\frac{1}{x}=1 \implies x^7+\frac{1}{x^7}=1$

Tags: functions, solution-verification, graphing-functions

$$x+\frac{1}{x}=1 \implies x^7+\frac{1}{x^7}=1$$

The graphs/range: $\quad y_1(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}, \quad y_7(x)=x^7+\frac{1}{x^7} \quad$
and do not touch the line $\quad y=1\quad$.  The relation $\quad x+\frac 1 x=1 \quad$ appears to only be true for certain complex values

Yet the reasoning for the implication itself is
\begin{align}
x+\frac {1}{x}&=1 \\
\color {green}{x^2}&=\color {green}{x-1 }\\
x^3&=\color {green}{x^2}-x \\
&=(\color {green}{x-1})-x \\
&=-1.
\end{align}
Hence $x^6=1$, which implies $x^7=x$.

I had just started reading this book when it was presented, asking you to prove the implication without finding the roots first.

So my question: is this implication really justified?   Should the author have said to only prove it for an implicit (complex) specific value of $x$?  If I didn't know any better, I'd say he presented it like it was true for some range of values...he couldn't of...

Comment: $x=\pm 1$ does not satisfy $x+\frac 1x=1$.

Comment: @lulu You're Right,  I'll Edit

Comment: One way is to note that if $a_n = x^n + \frac{1}{x^n}$ then we have the recursion $a_{n+1} = a_n a_1 - a_{n-1}$

Comment: I don't see any reason to look at the real intersections of $y_1(x),y_2(x)$.  They have nothing to do with the problem.  You want the (complex) solution to $y_1(x)=0=y_2(x)$ if you intend to solve the problem by finding the values of $x$.

Comment: @lulu I guess from the way the question was delivered, it seemed that such an implication should have a better reason to be true other than them agreeing at one or two values of $x $

Comment: "Such roots would have to be imaginary..." This problem is not so much to do with complex numbers, instead it is about fields (in the sense of abstract algebra): the steps of this proof are all consequences of the axioms of a field. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Comment: The intersections, other than the one with $y=0$ have nothing whatsoever to do with the problem.

Comment: @lulu I Was Going For A Graphical Reason For The Implication

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what point you are making.  The graphs you wrote down have nothing to do with the problem.  I don't know what a graphical interpretation of the problem would look like....strikes me as a purely algebraic problem (in particular, it holds over any field).  It is true that, were you to plot these graphs over $\mathbb C$ you would see the two relevant intersections...but that is literally equivalent to the given problem (over $\mathbb C$ anyway).

Comment: @lulu I Guess we're coming from different viewpoints. I don't automatically think $x\implies x^7$ in general.  If it does I wanna see the repercussions any way I can.

Comment: What does $x\implies x^7$ mean?  It is certainly not true that $x^7+\frac 1{x^7}$ is always equal to $x+\frac 1x$ !  Happily, you weren't asked to show anything of the sort.

Comment: @lulu I mis-typed, I meant the original implication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define two propositions: $p:= x+\frac{1}{x}−1=0$ and $q:=x^7+\frac{1}{x^7}−1=0$. You are trying to find the values of $x$ for which $p \wedge q$ is true. The actual question is 'prove that $p \Rightarrow q$ is true'. These two propositions are different.

If you try to solve $x+\frac{1}{x}=1$ you end up with $x = e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$ and $x = e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}$. Now, in both cases
$$x^7+\frac{1}{x^7} = 2\cos \frac{7\pi}{3} = 2\cos \frac{\pi}{3} = 1.$$

Comment: I rephrase my comment: I do not understand why you are looking at the intersection of those two curves.

Comment: Because if one relation implies another I want to see how it's justified graphically as well

Comment: Define two propositions: $p : x+\frac{1}{x}-1=0$ and $q : x^7+\frac{1}{x^7}-1 = 0$. You are trying to find the values of $x$ for which $p \wedge q$ is true. The actual question is 'prove that $p \Rightarrow q$ is true'. These two propositions are different.

Comment: A VERY important distinction, yet the latter is the one presented in the book

Comment: Have I answered your question...?

Comment: are you saying the book is wrong?  Or that the implication is weak?

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate -- Do you know how the logical implication works? If the antecedent is false, then the statement is true.

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate I am just asking if you were convinced by my last comment above.

Comment: @mr_e_man I'm aware.   Just not used authors actually using that in their writing.

Comment: @Gibbs after stepping away I see now that the statement from the book WAS about particular values of $x $ and not an overall relation between a set of numbers.  Your distinction was key and I wish you would include it in your answer.

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate Glad that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n:=x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}$ so $x_{n+1}=x_1 x_n - x_{n-1}=x_n - x_{n-1}$ and $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}-x_n=-x_{n-1}$. Thus $x_7=(-1)^2x_1=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The given equation implies $x^2-x+1=0$; multiplying by $x+1$, we get $x^3+1=0$. This implies $x^6=1$ and therefore
$$
x^7=x
$$
Your argument is sound as well.

The key is that a solution to $x+\frac{1}{x}=1$ is a 6th root of $1$. Indeed,
$$
x^6-1=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)
$$
Thus any root of $x^2-x+1$ is also a root of $x^6-1$.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to find where $y_1=y_2$, but whether a root of $y_1$ is necessarily a root of $y_2$.

That is,

$$\forall x\Big(y_1(x)=0\implies y_2(x)=0\Big)$$

or equivalently,

$$\forall x\Big(y_1(x)\neq0\lor y_2(x)=0\Big)$$

Comment: Thank you.   I was trying to generalize a statement that was really only about a couple values of $x $